# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova disabled emulator target dropdown after Update 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I just updated my Visual Studio 2015 to the latest Tools for Apache Cordova Update 8.1. I am now not able to select any emulators because the debug target dropdown is disabled. How can I get it re-enabled?

I have tried "Clear Cordova Cache" under Options and rebuilding the solution, but it's still disabled. Prior to updating from Update 8 to 8.1, everything was working fine.

This is what my toolbar looks like now:
[image: disabled debug target]

**Update**

I have tried repairing VS 2015, then uninstalling TACO, reinstalling TACO Update 8.1. Now when I load up a Cordova project, the *Debug Target* dropdown is enabled, but only with the Google Android Emulator and Ripple emulators in the list. I cannot add any VS Android Emulators. Upon loading the project, I'm getting this error:

[image: ApacheCordovaToolsPackage did not load correctly]

Looking at the **ActivityLog.xml**, at the very end, I see this error:

```
<entry>
    <record>765</record>
    <time>2016/04/19 14:55:50.168</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage][Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]:{   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)}</description>
    <guid>{317A330D-8757-4084-8526-E8A1D165433D}</guid>
    <hr>80131604</hr>
    <errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I tried Michael's suggestion of running the `devenv` commands, but I'm still getting the same errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try opening a developer command prompt as administrator and running devenv /setup, and then devenv /updateconfiguration?

Comment: @MichaelBraude I tried the commands, but still getting errors. See my update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for posting the PLF error, that's very helpful. It looks like the MEF cache is bad or corrupted. I can't tell why, but to fix it, can you close VS, delete this directory and retry? %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: @MichaelBraude Thanks. Deleting that directory made the error message go away, but the debug target dropdown is still disabled. I even re-ran the devenv commands.

Answer (score 0):

After having Microsoft developers tried to help me to no avail, I started using TACO CLI and VS Code as an alternative (a pretty good one except it lacked the *JavaScript Language Service* output which enabled me to see all the console outputs). However, I think I finally found a fix to re-enable the target dropdown.

Initially, I tried removing VS 2015 Update 2 and reinstalling it. That actually enabled the dropdown for a few days. Then one day it started being disabled again. This is what I did to re-enable the dropdown:

1. Close your solution in VS 2015.
2. Open up the file "*%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\configurationsBackup.xml* ".
3. Search for a device profile you have installed using **Visual Studio Emulator for Android**. Copy the **id** attribute value from that `<configuration>` tag. Copy the `device.name` value as well.
4. Open your app's *.jsproj.user* file. Under the `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Android'">` item, change the value in `<AndroidEmulatorID>` to the ones you copied from **configurationBackup.xml**. For example, for the 5.7" Android 5.0 profile, the entire tag will be 
   `<AndroidEmulatorID>61B433CF-8C92-4CEA-9CA1-009DC946ED7E;VS Emulator 5.7" Lollipop (5.0) XHDPI Phone</AndroidEmulatorID>`
5. Save the *.jsproj.user* file. Open your solution from VS 2015.

Not sure if all the steps were necessary, but it enabled the dropdown for me. Hope this helps anyone who encounters this issue.